# Trying to Loop Through Array of Tickers and Download All Tables from Web

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I think this code snippet is close to working, but it doesn't download data from the website that it's pointed to.  I am trying to download the table named 'fs-table' and I want to put each 'fs-table' on individual Excel worksheets.

```
# pip install -U multi-mechanize
import mechanize
mech = mechanize.Browser()
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

mech = Browser()

tckr = ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']
url = "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:" + tckr + "&fstype=ii"
page = mech.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("fs-table", border=1)

url_list = [url + s for s in tckr]

for url in url_list:
    try:
        wb1 = Workbook()
        ws1 = wb1.active
        wb1 = load_workbook('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/template.xlsx')
        wb1.create_sheet(tckr)
        with open('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/today.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:   
            for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
                col = row.findAll('td')
                rank = col[0].string
                artist = col[1].string
                album = col[2].string
                cover_link = col[3].img['src']
                record = (rank, artist, album, cover_link)
                print("|".join(record))

    except HTTPError:
        print("{} - not found".format(url))
    wb1.save('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/template.xlsx')
```

Here is the website I am trying to work with.

[image]

Now, I am getting this message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mechanize'

But, I already installed multi-mechanize!

[image]

I am using Python 3.6.1; Spyder 3.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will fetch you the tabular data from that site.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:{}&fstype=ii"

def Get_Table(ticker):   
    response = requests.get(URL.format(ticker))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    table = soup.select_one("#fs-table")
    for items in table.select(" tr"):
        data = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select("th,td")]
        print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for tckr in ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']:
        Get_Table(tckr)
```

Comment: Yeah, I had to wait until I got home to run this; the proxy in my office blocks EVERYTHING!  It works perfect.  So, that's the Income Statements.  How would you go about getting the Balance Sheet data and Cash Flow data?  I noticed the URL is the same.  Would it require clicking the links for each of the other two financial statements?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

replace your

```
from mechanize import Browser
```

by

```
import mechanize
```

and your

```
mech = Browser()
```

by

```
mech = mechanize.Browser()
```

BTW, url = "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:" + tckr + "&fstype=ii", while tckr has not yet been defined.  My knowledge of python is limited.